# return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am new to djnago.When I am about to run the command

> python manage.py migrate

above mentioned error is coming.I don't know where I am wrong.
My populate_rango.py file is

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',   'tango_with_django_project.settings')


import django
django.setup()

from rango.models import Category, Page


def populate():
   python_cat = add_cat('Python')

   add_page(cat=python_cat,
     title="Official Python Tutorial",
     url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/")

   add_page(cat=python_cat,
     title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
     url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/")

   add_page(cat=python_cat,
     title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
     url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/")

   django_cat = add_cat("Django")

   add_page(cat=django_cat,
     title="Official Django Tutorial",
     url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/")

   add_page(cat=django_cat,
     title="Django Rocks",
     url="http://www.djangorocks.com/")

   add_page(cat=django_cat,
     title="How to Tango with Django",
     url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/")
  frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks")

   add_page(cat=frame_cat,
     title="Bottle",
     url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/")

   add_page(cat=frame_cat,
     title="Flask",
     url="http://flask.pocoo.org")

# Print out what we have added to the user.
   for c in Category.objects.all():
      for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
         print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views):
  p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
  p.url=url
  p.views=views
  p.save()
  return p

def add_cat(name,views,likes):
  c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
  c.views=views
  c.likes=likes
  c.save()
  return c

# Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print "Starting Rango population script..."
  populate()
```

the error is

```
 Applying rango.0002_auto_20151102_1020...Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
 execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management  /__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
field,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 179, in add_field
self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 77, in _remake_table
self.effective_default(field)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
prepared=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 702, in get_db_prep_value
value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1868, in get_prep_value
return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

0002_auto_20151102_1020 file is

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

   dependencies = [
      ('rango', '0001_initial'),
    ]

   operations = [
      migrations.AddField(
          model_name='category',
          name='likes',
          field=models.IntegerField(default=1),
          preserve_default=False,
       ),
      migrations.AddField(
          model_name='category',
          name='views',
          field=models.IntegerField(default=''),
          preserve_default=False,
      ),
]
```

models.py is

```
 from django.db import models

 # Create your models here.
 class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views=models.IntegerField()
    likes=models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):  #For Python 2, use __str__ on Python 3
        return self.name

 class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):      #For Python 2, use __str__ on Python 3
        return self.title
```

Please help me.Thanks for spending you time...

Comment: Where does the error say the error is coming from? what line/method?

Comment: @Sayse I have updated the error.You can see where it is coming from...

Comment: can we see the content of `0002_auto_20151102_1020` migration file?

Comment: @doniyor I have updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have

```
migrations.AddField(
      model_name='category',
      name='views',
      field=models.IntegerField(default=''), # <---- problem line
      preserve_default=False,
),
```

`IntegerField` needs integer, not strings ;)

in your `Category` model, you need

```
views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and then run the commands again:

```
makemigrations
migrate
```